# Linux: how to wait for another process to block on a POSIX semaphore?

Tags: linux, ipc, semaphore, shared-memory, race-condition

I have a Linux process, call it "slave', that for architectural reasons exists first, that creates some POSIX Shared Memory (SHM) and a POSIX Semaphore. Then it spawns another process, call it "master". Both processes will use these resources to coordinate the process of the *master* sending request data to the *slave*, and the *slave* returning data to the *master* in response. The key function of the semaphore is to protect access to SHM.

Assuming we reach a state where the slave is blocked and the master is not (semaphore is `0`, slave is waiting due to `sem_wait`):

1. at some arbitrary time, the master writes request data to SHM.
2. master calls `sem_post`, immediately waking slave (semaphore remains `0`).
3. master calls `sem_wait`, blocks because semaphore is `0`.
4. newly awakened slave reads request data from SHM, calculates result, writes result to SHM.
5. slave calls `sem_post`, immediately waking master (semaphore remains `0`).
6. slave calls `sem_wait`, blocks because semaphore is `0`.
7. newly awakened master reads result data from SHM.

NB: the semaphore remains `0` after each `sem_post` because the other process (the blocked one) immediately wakes up and decrements it. I don't think either process ever sees it with value `1` as the wake-up is atomic.

At this point, the slave is blocked and the master is not, so the entire process can be repeated over and over, as dictated by the master.

The problem I'm having is getting into this initial state. Because the slave is responsible for spawning the master, it needs a way to block *before* the master gets the chance to write to SHM. But the slave can't block before it spawns the master, as then it can't actually spawn it. If it blocks immediately after spawning the master, there is a race where the master can write to SHM before the slave actually blocks, causing the master to fail to wait for the slave response, and therefore reading invalid data from SHM. Unlikely but it's a valid race condition.

So I'm searching for an efficient but most importantly correct (race free) way to untangle this - essentially I need to have the master somehow wait for the slave to block before commencing execution, but I don't want to resort to polling or arbitrary delays unless I have to.

Does this kind of problem have a name? It feels like an inversion of control, but I'm not sure how having the master create/initialise the semaphore would work either. I need to get the two processes into the correct lock-step.

I did consider a third process, that is responsible for creating the semaphore, then spawning the slave, waiting until it blocks, and then spawning the master, but I feel like this is the same problem, because how can the first process test for a blocked slave process with the POSIX Semaphore API?

Comment: can you share a minimal example to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I'll need some time to construct a minimal example, because I wasn't prepared to spend a lot of time writing the code before fixing this design issue, given that it probably won't actually work. I'll update this question once I have some suitable code.